I got Scammed on an ETH Smart pool contract
I got Scammed on an ETH Smart pool contract, which is still running and showing my account balance $25740 withdrawable and $1866+$2 additionally showing me in the blockchain.
They starting a new pool automatically and asking to deposit  minimum $5000 so that next round of mining can be eligible
I'm able to see only $2 in my wallet and I had $1866 till yesterday.
Is there any way, I can transfer these funds as scammer are still insisting me to pay them more to qualify for the next round of contract?
